# How to immediately display result after delete the search field ReactJS + Antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working on the searching of table using ReactJs and Antd. What I want to do is when I delete the input field, the table will immediately re-render and show the full data while I don't need to press Enter or click on the Search button. Is there any way to do that? Thank you.

Code here

```
const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([])

const handleSearch = (value) => {
    let newData = [...data]
    const filterData = arrClone.filter((o) => Object.keys(o).some((k) => String(o[k])
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(value.toLowerCase())));
    setDataSource(filterData);
  };
```

Search field and Table

```
<Row>
   <Col lg={24}>
       <Search
         size='large'
         placeholder='Search something'
         enterButton='Search'
         prefix={<SearchOutlined />}
         style={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
         allowClear
         onSearch={handleSearch}
       />
       <Table
         columns={columns}
         dataSource={dataSource}
         rowSelection={rowSelection}
       />
     </Col>              
</Row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the onChange property to `Search` and pass your handleSearch function into it

Comment: So I can add the onChange={handleSearch} under the onSearch one? Right?

Comment: `onChange={(e)=>{handleSearch(e)}}`
and insdie handleSearch get the value e.target.value

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It work as I desired, but could you explained for me why you came up with the solution? I just don't understand it yet.

Comment: onChange is triggered when the input field is changed and your req. is exactly the same so passing the search function into it